# Is "Interested in" used only about hobbies?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say “I am interested in watching this film”?
May be it is better to say “I would be interested in watching this film”?
Or do you use “interested in” only about hobbies?

Comment: It's fine to say “I am interested in watching this film”. The second option is a little more awkward. It might work better as “I would be interested to watch this film”. (But better would be "I wouldn't mind watching this film" or "I'd like to watch this film" etc.)

Comment: A scientist could say they were _interested in_ the topic they were researching.